# Trying to check the index of a textinput text but recieving error

Tags: python, kivy

Im trying to check the index of a kivy TextInput text but it tells me that the index is out of range. Here is my code.

```
        self.creditCardField = TextInput(size_hint = (.6, .07), pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.70}, font_name = "fonts/Qanelas-Light.otf")
        self.creditCardField.hint_text = "Card Number"
        self.creditCardField.input_filter = 'int'
        self.add_widget(self.creditCardField)
        self.creditCardField.bind(text = self.on_text_card)
        self.creditCardField.bind(text = self.verification)
        self.creditCardImage = Image(pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.80, "center_y": 0.70})
        self.add_widget(self.creditCardImage)

    def verification(self, instance, value):
        if value[0] == "4":
            self.creditCardImage.source = "cardicons/visa.png"
        if value[0] == 5 and value[1] < 6 and value[1] > 0:
            self.creditCardImage.source = "cardicons/mastercard.png"
        if value[0:2] in (36, 38):
            self.creditCardImage.source = "cardicons/dinersclub.png"
        if value[0:4] == 6011 or value[0:2] == 65:
            self.creditCardImage.source = "cardicons/discover.png"
        if value[0:2] == 35:
            self.creditCardImage.source = "cardicons/jcb.png"
        if value[0:2] in (34, 37):
            self.creditCardImage.source = "cardicons/americanexpress.png"
```

Thank you for the assistance

Comment: Your `verification` function has two arguments, but you don't send `value` there.

Comment: @Lothric don’t understand bro

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm wrong, I don't remember exactly what arguments are being sent to function from `bind`. I'm talking about `self.creditCardField.bind(text = self.verification)`. But if it works correctly there's a situation. When you put the first character to your `creditCardField` your `verification` function starts to work. And there is `if value[0:2]` and `if value[0:4]` - so your `value` index is out of range because you have only one character there. So you need to put some other `if` statement to check the length of the value before other checks.

Comment: @Lothric make sense bro, I’ll try that

Comment: That worked bro, just put a condition that says if the length of the value is more than 0, the function should continue

Comment: @Lothric thanks a lot bro